# Need help selecting a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following form.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="save-user">
    <button type="button" name="save-user">Save</button>
    <button type="button" name="save-user-close">Save & Close</button>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
</form>
```

I am confused on how do i create a jQuery selector for all the inputs and buttons elements, as i am not using an id attribute, i do not want to use it in this case. how do i retrieve or create selector for all the four form elements.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above answers are ok, but you can, and most certainly should, learn and (learn to) use advanced selectors such [as pseudo classes, attribute selectors and more](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
Here are a few examples for you case:

```
// all the buttons that are children of the container 
//with the attribute id equal to "save-user"
$("#save-user").find('button');

// all the buttons that have their name attribute starting with "save-user"
$('button[name^=save-user]'); 

// same as before, only that we filter the results
// by checking if they contain the text "Save"
$('#save-user').find('button').filter(':contains(Save)');
```

You can create even more complex queries only with the use of jquery selectors - withouth the need to bind an id or class to the elements - to suite your needs. Of course, the main downside would be efficiency, but if you don't abuse the special selectors, your jquery coding-style can be quite cool.

Answer (score 1):

how about ...
`$('#save-user button,#save-user input').blah();`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#save-user").find("button, input")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(':button[name="save-user"]')` for button and `$(':input[name="name"]')` for input.